# Picture in photo gallery no longer exists once I restart Flutter app (within Android Studio development environment)

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Within Android Studio Flutter development environment, I'm choosing a picture from its Photo Gallery, getting its file path and saving the path in database as text, and later retrieve the file path to refer back to the picture in the Photo Gallery.

This works fine, but once I restart the app (again, all within Android Studio), then the picture no longer loads as that file path is no longer valid.

Is Photo Gallery somehow specific to each Flutter session or something?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on how the native part is implemented and the plugin you are using. On Android when you request an image from the Gallery using an Intent, you may receive 'temporal access' to the file.

If you do not copy the image you may lose that permission to access the photo. You can ask the maintainer of the plugin or check if they use grantUriPermission to give access to the image file.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using ImagePicker Flutter package here and for ios, have added NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription for permissioning etc...  What's weird is that once I restart the app on my simulator, it looks like the directory path that used to have this image file is just gone.  I actually tried to CD into such directory and noticed that it was gone (again, this happens only when i restart the app on simulator). I'm hoping that this wouldn't happen once I try this app on actual iPhone or Android phone etc...  :)